# warning: variable 'b' set but not used

Tags: arduino-uno, variables

I got the following error:

`warning: variable 'b' set but not used`.

I think I do a really small thing wrong but I can't figure out what it is.

```
#define array_size(array) ((int)(sizeof(array) / sizeof((array)[0])))

typedef struct Boid {
  unsigned long start_animate_time;
} Boid;

Boid boids[4];


Boid create_boid() {
  unsigned long start_animate_time = 0L; 
  Boid b = {start_animate_time};
  return b;
}


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  boids[0] = create_boid();
  boids[1] = create_boid();
  boids[2] = create_boid();
  boids[3] = create_boid();

  for (int i = 0; i < array_size(boids); i++) {
    Boid b = boids[i]; // <<<<<<<<<<<<< this line!
    b.start_animate_time = 456;
  } 


  for (int i = 0; i < array_size(boids); i++) {
    Boid b = boids[i];
    Serial.println(b.start_animate_time); // BUG always 0
  }
}


void loop() {

}
```

> flock_01_ino_debug.ino:28:10: warning: variable 'b' set but not used
>   [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
>        Boid b = boids[i];
>             ^

Comment: I get `Symbol 'I' could not be resolved`. Change `I` to `i`.

Comment: @Jurai No idea how that became a capital since I copied pasted all code. I guess it is a safari auto correct that happened after I added `// <<<<<<<<<<<<< this line!` Since that is the only thing I added in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

C++ is not Java. You can't just assign structs like that - it copies them (if anything).

```
Boid b = boids[I]; // <<<<<<<<<<<<< this line!
b.start_animate_time = 456;
```

Instead just access the array slice directly:

```
boids[i].start_animate_time = 456;
```

And later on as well:

```
Serial.println(boids[i].start_animate_time);
```

Basically, you create a "Boid" variable called "b", copy the content of `boids[i]` to it, set a value in that variable, and then throw it away. Hence the "not used". If you want to reference a specific array slice as a separate variable either get a pointer to it:

```
Boid *b = &boids[i];
b->start_animate_time = 456;
```

Or use a reference:

```
Boid &b = boids[i];
b.start_animate_time = 456;
```

Of the two I prefer using a pointer, but I come from a C background and understand pointers, but it took me many years of trial and error to get to that point...

Comment: Thanks, I always struggle with references and pointers since my lack of experience with them.

Comment: Or you can use some C++11 features:  `for (auto & boid : boids) { boid.start_animate_time = 456; Serial.println(boid.start_animate_time); }`  (two loops are not needed here at all)

Comment: @KIIV Indeed - though be careful using `auto` - the meaning seems to change from C++ version to C++ version. Like they can't make their mind up what it's for.